# "красивое" изменение строки

Tags: python

Коллеги вопрос по строкам в питоне:
Есть список примерно следующий:

```
[['qwe', '123'], ['asdfd', 'qwe'], ['123', 'asd']]
```

на выходе мне нужно получить строку:

```
([qwe] 123, [asdfd] qwe, [123], asd)
```

на данный момент я использую следующий механизм (и с задачей справляется):

```
test = str(test).replace("', '", '] ').replace("'],", ', ').replace("[['", "([").replace("]]", ")]").replace("['", "[").replace("')]", ")")
```

но честно говоря код смотрится не очень эстетично! Есть ли механизмы позволяющие изящно обойти повторяющиеся конструкции `.replace`?
Спасибо!

Comment: почему в двух случаях после ] нет запятой, а в одном есть?

Answer (score 8):

Просто сразу создавайте строку нужного вида:

```
lst = [['qwe', '123'], ['asdfd', 'qwe'], ['123', 'asd']]
s = "({})".format(", ".join(f"[{first}] {second}" for first, second in lst))
print(s)
```

Вывод:

```
([qwe] 123, [asdfd] qwe, [123] asd)
```

Comment: не совпадает с тем, что надо. И в примере ошибка, или там какая-то хитрая логика.

Comment: @Эникейщик скорее всего в примере ошибка, потому что "референсная реализация" не добавляет там запятую

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну да, последняя запятая в примере явно лишняя

Comment: Как вариант можно использовать два вида кавычек и не смешивать `f-строки` и `format`: `f'({", ".join(f"[{first}] {second}" for first, second in lst)})'` Хотя в таком варианте легче запутаться в скобках ))

Comment: @CrazyElf лучше не использовать какие-то сложные выражения в f-строках, это легкий способ запутаться и выстрелить себе в ногу. В моем варианте прямо видно этапы справа налево - конвертируем каждый элемент, потом объединяем через запятую, потом оборачиваем в скобки, все ясно и понятно, по-моему.

Comment: @insolor  Эникейщик  большое спасибо! То что нужно и да там хитрая штука! ;) последовательность создана с определенной логикой! - эта строка ни что иное как часть кода для sql

Answer (score 0):

Красота в глазах смотрящего. На мой взгляд, ничего красивее функционального стиля пока не изобрели. А в сочетании с ООП получается еще лучше.

```py
import dataclasses
import itertools
from typing import Any, Iterable


# более релевантное имя класса и полей задайте самостоятельно
@dataclasses.dataclass
class MyRecord:
    field1: str
    field2: str

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'[{self.field1}] {self.field2}'


def comma_separated(xs: Iterable[Any]) -> str:
    return ', '.join(f'{x}' for x in xs)


def parens(x: Any) -> str:
    return f'({x})'


data = [['qwe', '123'], ['asdfd', 'qwe'], ['123', 'asd']]
records = itertools.starmap(MyRecord, data)
print(parens(comma_separated(records)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну как вариант:

```py
lst = [['qwe', '123'], ['asdfd', 'qwe'], ['123', 'asd']]
string = f'({", ".join([f"[{i[0]}] {i[1]}" for i in lst])})'
```